# A $d$-form on ${\mathbb R}^n$ that vanishes on $\binom{d+n-1}{n-1}$ general points, vanishes identically.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I'm looking for a reference for the fact that a $d$-form on ${\mathbb R}^n$ that vanishes on $p_1,..,p_{\binom{d+n-1}{n-1}}$ general points, vanishes identically. 
A specific construction of a set of points is also welcomed. 
Thank you.

Comment: And there are no constraints on $d$?  It has e.g. smooth coefficients that are functions of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @muaddib In the context of tags, a $d$-form is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ (rather than a differential form)

Comment: that makes it much clearer, thanks.

Comment: The Mairhuber–Curtis theorem deals with Haar bases of continuous functions. Are there examples of interpolating basis of non continuous functions for n>1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of the [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) of homogeneous polynomials $R_d(\mathbb R^n)$ is indeed $\binom{d+n-1}{n-1}$.

But for $n>1$ your claim does not hold for **all** layouts of the points. (It's a consequence of Mairhuber–Curtis theorem proving that there are no Haar spaces in $n>1$).

For example, take a linear $d=1$ polynomial $ax+by\in R_1$ on $\mathbb R^2$. The graph of $p=ax+by$, a plane, intersects the $xy$-plane along the line $ax+by=0$, so if the both ($\binom{d+n-1}{n-1}=2$) of our sample points are on the intersection line then $p=0$, but not necessarily $p\equiv0$. For the latter we need to take the second point to be not collinear with the first and the origin. Demanding that $p=0$ on these two points (and the origin) then leads to $p\equiv0$. Such arrangements of points are called *unisolvent*, at least in the field of approximation theory and multivariate polynomial interpolation. See, for example, the Definition 2.6 in Wendland's "Scattered data approximation". It basically says

**Definition.** Points are called
$\Pi$-unisolvent if the zero polynomial is the only polynomial from $\Pi$ that vanishes
on all of them.